# Regular expression: find spaces (tabs/space), but not newlines

Tags: regex

How can I have a regular expression that tests for spaces or tabs, but not newlines?

I tried `\s`, but I found out that it tests for newlines too.

I use [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) (.NET) and [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation), but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: It may matter. .NET regular expression functions have the *multi-line option*. None of the answers addresses that (even if the default value of it may suffice).

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Use character classes: `[ \t]`

Comment: Spot on for my problem. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/25956935/292060 for a perl-only `\h` character class, but it does show there are many other whitespace chars, in case you need to add them to the list here.

Comment: why should there have a space before `\t`?

Comment: @Ooker To capture a literal space

Comment: This won't match other kinds of spaces, as other answers have mentioned.

Comment: Why a space before \t ?

Answer (score 53):

Try this character set:

```
[ \t]
```

This does only match a space or a tabulator.

Answer (score 21):

As [Eiríkr Útlendi noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583111/regular-expression-find-spaces-tabs-space-but-not-newlines/36729658#36729658), the accepted solution only considers two white space characters: the horizontal tab ([U+0009](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x)), and a breaking space ([U+0020](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x)).  It does not consider other white space characters such as non-breaking spaces (which happen to be in the text I am trying to deal with).

A more complete white space character listing is included [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) and also referenced in the [linked Perl answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469080/). A simple C# solution that accounts for these other characters can be built using [character class subtraction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction):

```
[\s-[\r\n]]
```

Or, including Eiríkr Útlendi's solution, you get

```
[\s\u3000-[\r\n]]
```

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** For those dealing with [CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters) text (Chinese, Japanese, and Korean), the double-byte space (Unicode `\u3000`) is **not** included in `\s` for any implementation I've tried so far (Perl, .NET, [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), and Python).  You'll need to either normalize your strings first (such as by replacing all `\u3000` with `\u0020`), or you'll have to use a character set that includes this code point in addition to whatever other white space you're targeting, such as `[ \t\u3000]`.

If you're using Perl or PCRE, you have the option of using the `\h` shorthand for *horizontal whitespace*, which appears to include the single-byte space, double-byte space, and tab, among others.  See the *[Match whitespace but not newlines (Perl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469080/)* question for more detail.

However, this `\h` shorthand has not been implemented for .NET and C#, as best I've been able to tell.

Comment: Good point.  Java's `\h` (introduced in Java 8) does include `\u3000`, but `\s` does not, unless you set UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS mode (introduced in Java 7).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace **space**, the below code worked for me in C#.

```csharp
Regex.Replace(Line, "\\\s", "");
```

**For Tab**

```csharp
Regex.Replace(Line, "\\\s\\\s", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar teacher was likely not a programmer, so use a double-negative:

```
[^\S\r\n]
```

That is, not-not-whitespace (the capital `S` complements) or not-carriage-return or not-newline. Distributing the outer not (*i.e.*, the complementing `^` in the character class) with [De Morgan’s law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), this is equivalent to “whitespace but not carriage return or newline.” Including both `\r` and `\n` in the pattern correctly handles all of Unix (LF), classic Mac OS (CR), and DOS-ish (CR LF) [newline conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation).

If you’re using PCRE, [other options are available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469155/123109).

Answer (score 0):

The following regex would find spaces (tabs/space), but not newlines characters.

```
[^\S\r\n]+
```

Check this [regex demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/9f4978201093).