# RegExp for whitespaces without tabs

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to build a parser for a sonar-plugin where the tokens can contain spaces and tabs in order to use them for implementing a checking rule for spaces. Therefore, I want to store them to different tokens.

I set the space and tab as TokenType:

```
    .withChannel(regexp(TokenType.TAB, "\t"))
    .withChannel(regexp(TokenType.WHITESPACE, "\\s"))
```

But, tabs are regarded as spaces tokens as well, 
because in Java the regexp for `/s` matches any white space character (space, tab, line break, carriage return)

What's the right regexp to discriminate tabs from spaces?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583111/regular-expression-find-spaces-tabs-space-but-not-newlines and just turn it around

Comment: In my case, I need separate regexp and simply "[ ]" doesn't work for me :/

Comment: I've tried also: "[\\s^\t]" but still doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

```
.withChannel(new BlackHoleChannel("\n"))        //removes newlines from source code
.withChannel(regexp(TclTokenType.TAB, "\t"))    //matches tabs
.withChannel(regexp(TokenType.WHITESPACE," "))  //matches spaces
```

Spaces are matched correctly, and tabs are recognized. The key is on the `BlackHoleChannel`.

<sup>This is FILIaS's solution from [revision 15](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21117965/15) of the question.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the `TokenType` syntax but to get all the whitespace **without** tabs you could use:

```
[ \n\x0b\r\f]
```

Because `\s` is just a short form of writing `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`. Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: It's not a valid syntax for TokenType but regardless that in my case I don't even need newlines or end of lines just whitespaces, but the "[ ]" doesn't do my job

Comment: So what you call whitespaces means _spaces_?