# C# Beginner: Delete ALL between two characters in a string (Regex?)

Tags: c#, regex, windows

i have a string with an html code. i want to remove all html tags. so all characters between < and >.

This is my code snipped:

```
WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
SourceCode = wClient.DownloadString( txtSourceURL.Text );
txtSourceCode.Text = SourceCode;
//remove here all between "<" and ">"
txtSourceCodeFormatted.Text = SourceCode;
```

hope somebody can help me

Comment: What if `<` and `>` characters occur inside comments, scripts, strings etc.?

Comment: No, do not use Regex to parse HTML strings. A real nightmare is waiting for you. This is one of the most upvoted answer in SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/ The best approach is to use a specialized HTML parser like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Steve My favourite SO answer ever :)

Comment: Using the .NET XML-Parser might also work in this case? Or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
txtSourceCodeFormatted.Text = Regex.Replace(SourceCode, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

But, as others have mentioned, [handle with care](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/).

Comment: Be warned, though, that this could lead to unexpected behavior in rare cases!

Answer (score 3):

According to [Ravi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19524158/456814), you can use

```
string noHTML = Regex.Replace(inputHTML, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();
```

or

```
string noHTMLNormalised = Regex.Replace(noHTML, @"\s{2,}", " ");
```