# Remove HTML tags to Display code as a tooltip?

Tags: html, .net, tooltip, richtextbox

I have some data in HTML format which is obtained from a richtextbox. I want to set it as tooltip in a gridview. But the tooltip displays HTML tags.

How can it be formatted without these tags?

Comment: Where's the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is being answered here: [Remove HTML tags from string including &nbsp in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523913/remove-html-tags-from-string-including-nbsp-in-c-sharp)

or you can look here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags