# How to remove html tags from text using c#

Tags: c#

I have the string like

```
<p>There was a <b>.NET</b> programmer and he stripped the <i>HTML</i> tags.</p><br> </br>
```

how to remove those html tags from the given string

Comment: use an HTML processing library, like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523913/remove-html-tags-from-string-including-nbsp-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4):

Use `Htmlagilitypack`

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(data);
string text= document.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use **Regex.Replace** 
something like this would do the job

```
var input = "<p>There was a <b>.NET</b> programmer and he stripped the <i>HTML</i> tags.</p><br> </br>";
var filtered = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", "");
Console.WriteLine(filtered);
```