# How to remove HTML tags from string using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using CKEditor to enter details (The details contains html elements). after that the details will be bind into a grid. In this I want to  show the details without html tags in tooltip.

```
protected void grdStepMain_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                i++;
                string description = cell.Text;
                if (cell.Text.Length > 8 && (i == 2))
                    cell.Text = cell.Text.Substring(0, 8) + "....";
              string newdescription = Regex.Replace(description, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();
              cell.ToolTip = newdescription;
            }

        }
    }
```

But its not working please help me. 
Example:

```
string str= " &lt;h1&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-family:courier new,courier,monospace&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;457457&lt;/strong&gt; 544444444444457457457&lt;/span&gt;";

The result in tooltip should be 457457544444444444457457457
```

Regards
Jithesh A

Comment: what is the current result?

Comment: [Remove-Html-Tags](http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags)

Comment: No changes....Still getting same string value

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove HTML tags from string including &nbsp in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523913/remove-html-tags-from-string-including-nbsp-in-c-sharp)