# Regex Explanation of <[^>]+>|&nbsp; in C#

Tags: c#, html, regex

I found the working regex in the thread [Remove HTML tags from string including &nbsp in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523913/remove-html-tags-from-string-including-nbsp-in-c-sharp)

The following code

```
Regex.Replace(m.Text, "<[^>]+>", string.Empty);
```

does remove html tags pretty good :)

But can somebody explain it to me ?

I do not quite understand what [^>] means..

[^] should match anything.. why the extra ">"

Comment: Visit [this link](https://regex101.com/r/lJ2zY5/1), the description is on the right. Basically, `[^<]+` is a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches 1 or more characters other than a `<`.

Comment: non greedy search of `<...>`. it can be simplified to `<.*?>`. (Note: the greedy form is faster. i.e `[^<]+`)

Comment: Watch out when you name a post `what does this regex mean`. Somebody here will direct you to more info about regex than the application you're looking for. This removes all html tags, scripts and entities: Find `(?i)[&%](?:[a-z]+|(?:\#(?:[0-9]+|x[0-9a-f]+)));|<(?:script(?:\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+)?\s*>[\S\s]*?</script\s*|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:(?:(?:"[\S\s]*?")|(?:'[\S\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>` replace with ''