# c# Regex ignore optional tags around text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, regex

**Problem:**

So lets say I have the following string:

```
<p><span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">Description:</span>Thomas is currently
 developing a enterprise resource management course for Pluralsight </p>
```

I am trying to do a regex.replace to remove `<span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">Description:</span>`

Often times both the start tag and end tag will not be present so both of these must be optional. Also they won't always be spans. The only thing I can guarentee is that the word "Description:" will be present.

**What I've tried:**

This was as close as I could get:

```
(?:<.*>)?Description:(?:<\/.*>)?
```

Unfortunately the starting capture group is also grabbing the starting p tag. I need to make it so that there is never more than 1 start or end tag.

Also when I use it in a:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(?:<.*>)?Description:(?:<\\/.*>)?", "")
```

I'm being returned

```
</span>Thomas is currently developing a enterprise resource management course for Pluralsight </p>
```

with the end span tag which it should not be capturing and the starting p tag missing...

**EDIT:**
Although similar to the thread that @kblok posted I only want to remove the first surrounding tag if it's present. This thread is about removing all surrounding tags. Hence my problem with removing the p tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove HTML tags from string including &nbsp in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523913/remove-html-tags-from-string-including-nbsp-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Using regex to parse html is not a very good idea. You'll run into all sorts of problems. There is [HTML agility pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) you could try.

Comment: I'm working extensively with htmlagilitypack at the moment but in this scenario I believe regex would be  more appropriate. I have multiple delimiters in my text in which I am using regex to split at, highlight and extract. I can't always assume that a delimiter will be wrapped in a span tag.

Comment: Do you want to remove Description: even when it does not have any tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to worry about quoted angle brackets, you could use

```
(?:<[^<]*>)?Description:(?:<\/[^<]*>)?
```

Improved pattern to enforce start/end tag name match and around Description only, also remove Description: when tags are not present.

```
(?:(?<open><)(?<start>[^ >]+)[^<>]*>)?Description:\k<open>\/?\k<start>>|Description:
```

Comment: The question says "Often times both the start tag and end tag will not be present".  This pattern will still match `<p>` if there is no other tag between it an `Description:`

Comment: Not only that, but `[^<]*` will match beyond the next > and then require unnecessary backtracking.  You can either make * non-greedy like *?, or put > inside the negated character class, or both, like `[^<>]*?`

Comment: The new pattern will not match cases that don't have any tags around "Description:", nor tags that don't have any attributes or extra space.  But be careful, if you simply wrap the last part in an optional group, it begins to match <p> again.  For multiple occurrences in the same text, it can also match unexpected closing tags preceding the next "Description:".

Comment: I ran it without tags around Description and it works fine - it doesn't match, so it does nothing. I fixed the other issue. I don't see multiple Description in the question.

Comment: Re-read question, decided could be interpreted as remove Description: even when tags not present, so changed second option.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern explicitly excludes `<p>` tags.

```
(?:<(?!p>|/)[^<>]*>)?Description:(?:</[^<>]*>)?
```

This one does the same, but is more strict about matching opening and closing tags.  It also allows white space between tags

```
(?:<(?!p>|/)(?<tag>[^ >]+)(?=[ >])[^<>]*>)?\s*Description:\s*(?:<\/\k<tag>[^<>]*>)?
```

Considering VDWWD's warning, even this ugly thing might be a bit naive with all possible HTML formatting variations considered, but it should at least match well-formed, simple cases as you've described.