# Shell script containing a Perl one-liner has blank results

Tags: regex, linux, perl, command-line

I have a Perl one-liner that works fine on the command line:

```
perl -nle 'm"\w+:x:\d+:\d+:\S+:/S+:(\S+)$" and $h{$1}++; END{ print "$_: $h{$_}" foreach sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h }' /etc/textfile
```

I've put this into a shell file called `shell.sh` so the next guy won't have to copy/paste and can just run it:

```
#!/bin/sh
perl -nle 'm"\w+:x:\d+:\d+:\S+:/S+:(\S+)$" and $h{$1}++; END{ print "$_: $h{$_}" foreach sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h }' /etc/textfile
```

I try running this on the command line and get no results; it just loads a fresh prompt with no output.  Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here are some system specs:

> Linux version 2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64
>
> (gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC)
>
> GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Here's a bit from the text file:

```
rfink:x:140:140:rat fink:/var/lib/rfink:/sbin/nologin                                 
edible:x:16252:10001:eric idle:/users/eidle/:/bin/bash                                       
tsawyer:x:30855:10001:tom sawyer:/users/tsawyer/:/bin/bash                                
karthur:x:30886:10001:King Arthur:/users/karthur/:/bin/bash                                         
karthur:x:30886:10001:king arthur:/users/karthur/:/bin/bash                                         
jcash:x:30887:10001:john cash:/users/jcash/:/bin/bash                              
hpotter:x:30887:10001:harry potter:/users/hpotter/:/bin/bash                              
triddle:x:30956:10001:tom riddle:/users/triddle/:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Can you show a sample from the textfile?

Comment: Added.  I'm pretty sure the regex is sound because the one-liner works from the command line.  Something about the shell script seems to be mucking it up.

Comment: Is all the trailing whitespace in the sample from your question in `/etc/textfile` verbatim?

Comment: The last line nails it.  Each line has 1 trailing whitespace (the multiple whitespaces on all other lines happened in c/p).

Comment: This won't help, but why not convert the perl one-liner to a perl script rather than a bash script?

Comment: That would be the easiest thing to do, but this has been requested specifically as a .sh file.  So it goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Quick answer

```
perl -nle 'm"\w+:x:\d+:\d+:[^:]+:\S+:(\S+)\s*$" and $h{$1}++;
  END{ print "$_: $h{$_}" foreach sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h }' \
  /etc/textfile
```

Your regex had three issues.

1. The field after the group ID could have spaces, so replace that subpattern with `[^:]+` to match one or more non-colon characters.
2. You used the wrong slash in your subpattern for matching the home directory.
3. Insert `\s*` before `$` to allow optional trailing whitespace on each line.

Output:

```
/bin/bash: 7
/sbin/nologin: 1
```

### Other approaches

Perl has an awk mode, which would allow

```
perl -F: -lane '++$sh{$F[-1]};
  END{print "$_: $sh{$_}" for sort { $sh{$b} <=> $sh{$a} } keys %sh}' \
  /etc/textfile
```

Having to remove trailing whitespace seems to cancel the syntactic benefit.

```
perl -F: -lane '($sh = pop @F) =~ s/\s+$//; ++$sh{$sh};
  END{print "$_: $sh{$_}" for sort { $sh{$b} <=> $sh{$a} } keys %sh}' \
  /etc/textfile
```

You could use a pipeline to get the best of all worlds:

```
perl -pe 's/[^\S\n]+$//' /etc/textfile |
  perl -F: -lane 'print $F[-1]' |
    sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

The output transposes the columns, but you get the same information.

Note the use of the [regex double-negative technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469155/123109) in the pipeline’s first command for removing all whitespace except newlines.

```
      7 /bin/bash
      1 /sbin/nologin
```

### As a shell script

Your question asks for a shell script, so—to vibe off [daxim’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10689018/123109)—that is

```
#! /bin/sh

perl -MUser::pwent -le \
  '$_->shell && print $_->shell while $_ = getpwent' |
  sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Note that this does not handle the pathological case of a shell named `0`.

If you don’t necessarily want to read the system */etc/passwd*, then your script becomes

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo Usage: $0 passwd-file .. 1>&2
  exit 1
fi

perl -pe 's/[^\S\n]+$//' "$@" |
  perl -lne 'm|\w+:x:\d+:\d+:[^:]+:\S+:(\S+)$| && print $1' |
    sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Different systems use different formats, so I recommend nailing down your expectation as in the above rather than blindly printing the last field, whatever it is. This may mean coping with the occasional empty output.

Comment: Neat, this worked!  Actually I just lazied up that [^:]+ entry and changed that whole phrase between colons to another \S+.  Still not sure why the one-liner as I had it would give me results from the command line but not from within a .sh file.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I don't see how either could have generated output unless your users' home directories are /SSSSSSS, /SSSSS, and /SS (or there's a copy-paste error).

Comment: Yeah, most probably a problem with the wetware.  IIRC (this was all the way back on Friday so that's a longshot) I manually typed the code into the .sh script so I could easily have reversed that slash and broken the whole thing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Avoid ad-hoc regex when a [specialised parser](http://p3rl.org/User%3a%3apwent) exists.

```
perl -MUser::pwent=getpwent -e'
    while (my $pwent = getpwent) { $h{ $pwent->shell }++; }
    END { print "$_: $h{$_}\n" for sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h }
'
```

Avoid reg-ex when simpler constructs, like `split`, `index`/`substr`, `unpack` will do. Here I take advantage of [autosplit](http://p3rl.org/run#%2a-a%2a):

```
perl -F: -lane'
    $h{ $F[-1] }++;
    END { print "$_: $h{$_}" for sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h }
' /etc/textfile
```

This makes for much shorter, more readable programs.