# Regex pattern that matches any number include 1-9 except 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a regular expression pattern that matches any number including 1-9 numbers except 2?

My attempt:

```
([1-9][^2])
```

But this doesn't work for me.

Comment: ([1,3-9]) what about this

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian the regex by YograjGupta would also match comma. Eg "1,9,,,,,8" would match.

Comment: @Lepidosteus, yes you are right

Comment: Your pattern, since none of the answers (so far) explained, will match a single digit in the range 1-9 followed immediately by any character except "2".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can match the range of numbers before and after two with `[0-13-9]`, like this:

```
"4526".match(/[0-13-9]+/)
["45"]
"029".match(/[0-13-9]+/)
["0"]
"09218".match(/[0-13-9]+/)
["09"]
```

Comment: how regex recognize the difference between 1 & 13 in that range?

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian Regex doesnot know '13' thirteen. I knows only as a single char.

Comment: if i want to deny zero numbers too, how to do it?

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian: just remove the zero from the range, `[13-9]` should do it.

Comment: `0-1`? You can just say `01`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I was mostly trying to give a generic solution so he understands how it works, to avoid questions like "how to do it with 5 instead of 2". But in this case yes, `01` could be used instead.

Comment: Fair enough. And for Mohammad: note that this (and all of the answers so far) will match on strings that contain other characters too as long as those digits are somewhere in there. E.g., the regex will match `"abcdef 1543 ghij 222"` (but it will just match the "1543" part). To ensure there are no other characters anywhere in the string you need to do something like `/^[13-9]*$/`.

Answer (score 23):

Another way to do it:

```
/[^\D2]/
```

Which means, not a non-digit or 2.

Comment: Quite elegant, I like it :)

Comment: **Disclosure:** I found this neat trick out from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3469155/459516

Answer (score 3):

Or this is also the correct answer.

`/(?!2)\d/`

Answer (score 1):

This RegExp works: `/([013-9])/`