# How to check correctness of doxygen \return statements?

Tags: c, perl, sed, awk, doxygen

I have inherited some C source code with doxygen annotations in comments. Due to bit rot, some of the annotations for `\return` comment are now lies, i.e. a function has been converted to return void, but the `\return` comment is still there and says otherwise.

Example:

```
/*!
 * \brief   The foo function
 * \return  OK if successful, ERROR otherwise
 */
void foo(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Now I want to find all files where this is so. I thought of using grep/sed/awk/perl to find the `\return` and then print the next line that starts with `void`. A simple

```
 grep -E '(\\return|^void)' file ...
```

also prints all `\return` comments from non-void functions. I'm sure there is an easy way to *only* print the previous `\return` line if a `^void` line is seen.

Comment: May the downvoter care to elaborate what's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be all you need if all of your functions and their preceding comments follow the style you posted:

```
awk '/\\return/{cmt=$0} /^[[:alpha:]]/{ if (/^void/ && cmt) print cmt ORS $0; cmt=""}' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
/*!
 * \brief   The foo function
 * \return  OK if successful, ERROR otherwise
 */
void foo(void)
{
    ...
}

/*!
 * \brief   The bar function
 * \return  OK if successful, ERROR otherwise
 */
int bar(void)
{
    ...
}

$ awk '/\\return/{cmt=$0} /^[[:alpha:]]/{ if (/^void/ && cmt) print cmt ORS $0; cmt=""}' file
 * \return  OK if successful, ERROR otherwise
void foo(void)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $prev_return;

while (<>) {
  # assume letter in first column introduces a function return type
  if (my($return_type) = /^([^\W\d]\w*)/) {
    if ($return_type eq "void" && defined $prev_return) {
      print $prev_return;
    }
    undef $prev_return;  # reset after each function definition
  }
  elsif (/\\return\b/) {
    $prev_return = "$ARGV:$.: $_";
  }
}
continue {
  close ARGV if eof;  # reset $. at the end of each named file
}
```

Note: the pattern `[^\W\d]` uses the [double-negative technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469080/how-do-i-match-whitespace-but-not-newlines/3469155#3469155) to match “word characters” that are not digits, *i.e.*, letters and underscores.

Sample output:

```
$ cat file.c
/*!
 * \brief   The foo function
 * \return  OK if successful, ERROR otherwise
 */
void foo(void)
{
    ...
}

\return fdsklj
void bar(void)

void baz

$ ./doxygen-return-void file.c
file.c:3:  * \return  OK if successful, ERROR otherwise
file.c:10: \return fdsklj
```

Perl’s `<>`, also known as the diamond operator, makes writing Unix-style filters easy. This means you can name as many paths as you like.

```
$ ./doxygen-return-void file.c file.c
file.c:3:  * \return  OK if successful, ERROR otherwise
file.c:10: \return fdsklj
file.c:3:  * \return  OK if successful, ERROR otherwise
file.c:10: \return fdsklj
```

The program above will also consume the standard input, but the output is not terribly useful.

```
$ cat file.c | ./doxygen-return-void
-:3:  * \return  OK if successful, ERROR otherwise
-:10: \return fdsklj
```