# allow only letters and spaces validate jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate, alphanumeric

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
        }, "Only alphabetical characters");
```

But if I insert a double name like "Mary Jane" the space creates a problem. how can i allow spaces too in my rule?

Comment: Do you know what the `[a-z]` part means?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the whitespace character (`\s`) to your Regex:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Only alphabetical characters");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Only alphabetical characters");
```

and

```
$('#yourform').validate({
            rules: {
                name_field: {
                    lettersonly: true
                }
}
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`^\S\n`

add this to in between your square brackets

This is a double negative that checks for not-not-whitespace or not-newline.

It will only check for a **whitespace**, but not a newline.
Your test should look like this:

```
/^[a-z^\S\n]+$/i.test(value)
```

**Source:** [@Greg Bacon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469155/2808234)

**EDIT:** you may want to add `A-Z` as well for capital letters