# replace whitespace with comma in multiline string (doc string), but keeping end-of-line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, whitespace

I have a **multiline string** (and not a text file) like this:

```
x = '''
Index    Value         Max     Min    State
0    10    nan         nan     nan
1    20    nan         nan     nan    
2    15    nan         nan     nan     
3    25    20          10      1
4    15    25          15      2
5    10    25          15      4
6    15    20          10      3    
'''
```

The column white spaces are **unequal**.

I want to replace the `whitespace` with a `comma`, but keep the `end-of-line`.

So the result would look like this:

```
Index,Value,Max,Min,State
0,10,nan,nan,nan
1,20,nan,nan,nan    
2,15,nan,nan,nan     
3,25,20,10,1
4,15,25,15,2
5,10,25,15,4
6,15,20,10,3
```

...or alternatively as a `pandas` dataframe.

what i have tried

- I can use `replace('')` with different spaces, but need to count the white spaces
- I can use the `re` module (from here [re.sub question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949752/re-sub-replace-spaces-with-comma) ), but it converts the whole string to 1 line, where as i need to keep multiple lines (end-of-line).

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469080/match-whitespace-but-not-newlines) can help.

Comment: potentially, but how to implement with preserving the end-of-lines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `StringIO`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd


x = '''
Index    Value         Max     Min    State
0    10    nan         nan     nan
1    20    nan         nan     nan    
2    15    nan         nan     nan     
3    25    20          10      1
4    15    25          15      2
5    10    25          15      4
6    15    20          10      3    
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

   Index  Value   Max   Min  State
0      0     10   NaN   NaN    NaN
1      1     20   NaN   NaN    NaN
2      2     15   NaN   NaN    NaN
3      3     25  20.0  10.0    1.0
4      4     15  25.0  15.0    2.0
5      5     10  25.0  15.0    4.0
6      6     15  20.0  10.0    3.0
```

Comment: and then chain with `to_csv()` :-)

Comment: this works !! presumably you need to add `import pandas as pd`... would you like to add that to the answer.

Comment: there were two great answers (upvoted both), but i have accepted this, just because it is a bit shorter on the line string.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged pandas, you can try:

```
out = ('\n'.join(pd.Series(x.split('\n')).str.strip().str.replace('\s+',',', regex=True)))
```

Output (note that there are leading and trailing blank lines because your `x` does):

```
Index,Value,Max,Min,State
0,10,nan,nan,nan
1,20,nan,nan,nan
2,15,nan,nan,nan
3,25,20,10,1
4,15,25,15,2
5,10,25,15,4
6,15,20,10,3
```

Comment: well pointed out.  i presume here, one needs to `import pandas as pd` to make out work.