# regex replace zero or more spaces at the end of a line with exactly two spaces

Tags: regex, notepad++, markdown

How do you replace a line ending with a non-whitespace followed by zero or more spaces, by the matched non-whitespace followed by exactly two spaces, leaving the newline character intact?

Searching for this:

```
(\S)(\h*)$
```

will match. Replace with this:

```
\1  (?# two spaces after the one)
```

*will* leave the [newline intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469080/match-whitespace-but-not-newlines-perl) so that's OK. I was hoping it would discard the second match (`\h*` matches all whitespace except newline), but it doesn't. It leaves the second match, and adds two spaces in front of it.

**Edit:** This is an example. For clarity, [cr] is newline (CR + LF in windows),  [sp] denotes 1 space, [2sp] 2 spaces, etc.

```
eggs[cr]
bacon;[2sp][cr]
[cr]
sausage.[3sp][cr]
```

should become

```
eggs[2sp][cr]
bacon;[2sp][cr]
[cr]
sausage.[2sp][cr]
```

Use case is writing markdown in Notepad++. I usually forget the two spaces marking <\br> I want to fix that with a regex search/replace. I know markdown is OK with two or more spaces, but still, it'd be cleaner to have just two. Without any additional search/replace of triple-or-more spaces, preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just do:

Find what: `(?<=\S)\h*$`
Replace with:  (two spaces)

Comment: That would also put double spaces on blank lines, and add trailing double-spaces to non-blank lines that already have trailing double-spaces.

Comment: @RolfBly: Pleasse, edit your question and give sample text and expected result.

Comment: @CHARLIE voilà, monsieur