# Why does my regex fail to match a string containing a tab?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a regular expression, but it does not work properly. The regular expression is:

```
m/^alias ([^\s]*) (.*) (<.*>)/
```

I tested my expression on a mutt file to convert it into a vcard. My string for the test is:

```
alias     john smith <john.smith@test.com>
```

But between `alias` and `john` I have a tab, and `([^\s]*)` doesn't find the tab. Why not? Normally `\s` matches spaces or tabs, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You have a literal space after `alias` in the pattern, so the first 6 characters of the string being matched must be "`a`", "`l`", "`i`", "`a`", "`s`" and space. But the sixth character of your string is a tab. I think you want the following:

```
my ($gname, $sname, $addr) = /^alias\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+<(.*)>/;
```

or

```
my ($name, $addr) = /^alias\s+([^<\s]+(?:\s+[^<\s])*)\s+<(.*)>/
```

(`\S` is equivalent to `[^\s]`.)

Answer (score 0):

`[^...]` are negated character classes. `\s` is a wildcard for whitespace characters (including tabs: `[ \t\r\n\f]`). `([^\s]*)` will capture every non-whitespace character.

As a side note, capitalizing a shorthand character class negates it. So, `[^\s]` is the same as `\S`.

Comment: (`\s` actually matches 25 chars. Those are merely the ASCII chars it matches.)

Comment: @Sam: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25956935/622310) talks about matching whitespace