# Can Python's regex be prevented from crossing newlines with '\s'?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

When performing a regex search in Python, even when `re.MULTILINE` isn't enabled,

The expression `A[\s]B` will match against

```
A
B
```

Since a newline matches `\s`.

Besides splitting the string into lines and operating on each - Is there an efficient way to make the expressions delimit on newlines?

---

Edit: I know its possible to use `[\t ]` or `[^\S\r\n]`, the issue is I don't control the input in this case, users will enter `\s` and won't expect it to spand lines. I'm not interested to try to tell the users they are wrong, from their perspective this is a bug.

So if the answer is *"it can't be done without splitting lines"* - so be it.

---

Note that operating on a file line by line is approximately twice as slow in my tests.

Comment: Do you ask how to match only *horizontal whitespace*?

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: Use `[^\S\r\n]`

Comment: The issue is I'm writing a program where the expressions are input from the users, so I would like `\s` to behave usefully and not catch newlines. I could replace `\s` with something else, but this seems risky.

Comment: No, ask the users to use correct patterns if they are allowed to input regular expressions. That is the correct way.

Comment: In this context the behavior they would want is to have \s match only horizontal whitespace (I think), so probably I just need to split the file by lines and match against those.

Comment: Yes, then it is the only way. However, it is much better to let users know how the tool works, and let them use what they want. They can't expect  `\s`  not to match line breaks, it is what it always does.

Comment: The other question is about perl, also I know *how* to match non-vertical whitespace, I want to know how to use `\s` without it matching vertical whitespace.

Comment: And [here is your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17752989/3832970). And [here is another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25955005/3832970). All in one and the same thread. Python `re` is also based on a Perl regex flavor. To make `\s` fail to match a line break char, you need to modify the pattern: 1) use a negated character class with an opposite shorthand character class and the line break chars or 2) use a negative lookahead that will restrict the `\s` pattern.

Comment: I've figured out my own answer, which allows using `\s`, avoids splitting lines to maych and is not on those threads, which is hint to me that this isn't a duplicate. Would like to reopen so I can post it.

Comment: Please post, let's revise it.

Comment: Here you go, inform users that both `\s` and `\h` are available and tell them the difference. Then import the _`regex`_ library into your program. Or, if you're determined to use `re`, then find `(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\\h` and replace `$1[^\S\r\n]` before compiling and running the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, `\s` is just a shorthand for `[ \t\r\n\f]`

Which means that running replace all `([^\\]|^)(\\\\)*\\s` with `$1$2[ \t\r\n\f]` on the regex pattern will have no effect. (have to not capture escaped `\s`) So TECHNICALLY, you can just simplify the above so that the character class `\s` is only `[ \t]`.

Of course, as others have said, changing the functionality of regex without telling the end user is very very bad, and it would probably be easier to explain/implement replacing all spaces in the regex with the character class `[ \t]` (as this is a smaller change to the base rule set). If there is a special reason the end user thinks `\s` can't capture new lines, than you should probably parse the file the same way the end user expects so that the code logic matches the end user logic.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, Python's regex cant be made so that `\s` wont match `\n`.

What you can do is detect '\n' in the matches and skip over those.

```
def finditer_delimit_newlines(pattern, string, delimit_newlines=True):
    matches = list(re.finditer(pattern, string))
    if not matches:
        return []

    end = matches[-1].start()
    newline_table = {-1: 0}
    for i, m in enumerate(re.finditer(r'\n', string), 1):
        offset = m.start()
        newline_table[offset] = i
        if offset > end:
            break

    for m in matches:
        m_start = m.start()
        m_end = m.end()
        newline_offset = string.rfind('\n', 0, m_start)
        newline_end = string.find('\n', m_end)
        if delimit_newlines:
            if ((newline_table[newline_offset] + 1) !=
                (newline_table[newline_end]
                 if newline_end != -1 else len(newline_table))
            ):
                continue
        yield m


search = """A
B

A B"""

import re

for delimit_newlines in (False, True):
    print("Test:", delimit_newlines)
    for a in finditer_delimit_newlines(r'[A-Z]\s[A-Z]', search, delimit_newlines):
        print(a)
```

This test outputs

```
Test: False
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='A\nB'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(5, 8), match='A B'>
Test: True
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(5, 8), match='A B'>
```

---

Edit, a match can capture trailing newlines as part of regular whitespace,
while its possible to detect this, it might be simpler use a similar method that re-matches the results on limited ranges if newlines exist.