# Replace possible blank space at the beginning of the line

Tags: regex, perl, search, replace

So I try to replace blank space at the beginning of the line like so.

Original :

```
this
 is

\tsome
  text
```

What I want :

```
+this
+is
+
+some
+ text
```

I tried to use this regex to do that :

```
echo -e 'this\n is\n\n\tsome\n  text' |
perl -wpe 's/^\s?(.*)/+$1/'
```

But this is the result for that :

```
+this
+is
++some
+ text
```

So my line with no text at all is not processed correctly. Or rather, I don't understand why it behaves like that.

Any idea why ?

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you can use `\h` instead of `\s` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469080/match-whitespace-but-not-newlines).

Comment: Ah, yes, that was that simple, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You are replacing the line-ending Line Feed. One solution is to remove it before the match and re-add it afterwards. This can be done using `-l`.

```
perl -ple's/^\s?/+/'
```

Alternatively, you could remove the Line Feed from the set of characters you are matching.

```
perl -pe's/^[^\S\n]?/+/'
```

If you're ok with also leaving VT, FF, CR, LINE SEPARATOR and PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR in place, you can shorten the above to the following:

```
perl -pe's/^\h?/+/'
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by sticky bit in the comment, I just have to replace \s by \h.
This is solved !

Comment: Also, you don't need to capture the rest of the line: `s/^\h?/+/` is enough