# Java replace all occurrences of whitespace in a string except last

Tags: java, regex

Suppose i have a string: `"10 000,00 EUR"` or `"1 000 000,00 EUR"`.

I would like to remove all whitespaces from the string except the last one, so the result would be like: `"10000,00 EUR"` or `"1000000,00 EUR"`.

At the moment I have something like this:

```java
String myString = "1 000 000 EUR";

myString = myString.replace("\\s(?=\\s*\\s)", "")
```

I assume that I should use a regex lookahead expression, which matches a whitespace that also has another whitespace following it? Any answer to solve the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: find last space (`lastIndexOf`) and replace all spaces before that (substring); or, use split on spaces and rejoin tokens adding space fo last. But what about deleting whitespaces that are between digits?

Comment: or just `"\\s+(?=.*\\s.*)"` that is, matches spaces  that are followed by anything containing one space / for spaces between digits: `"(?<=\\d)\\s+(?=\\d)"`

Comment: I used `"\\s+(?=.*\\s.*)"` to solve my problem. Thank you, @CarlosHeuberger

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Regex r = new Regex("\\s");
myString = myString.replace(r, "");
```

and if you want to be sure that it's not the last space:

```
Regex m = new Ragex("\\s\\S+^"); \\means: tha last space.
myString = myString.replace(m, "@@@@"); \\escape the last space.
myString = myString.replace(r, ""); \\delete the other spaces.
myString = myString,replace("@@@@", " "); \\put back the last space on place we marked.
```

The process is, for example:

myString = "100 00 0 ER"

```
=>"100 00 0@@@@ER" 
=>"100000@@@@ER"
=>"100000 ER"
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I gave just the idea...that has to be "\\s"?

Comment: Thanks. "\\s" is better?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

`[^\S\r\n](?=[0-9])`

The idea is to match the whitespace characters except a line-feed or a carriage-return that are followed by a digit.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469155/2912665) answer to understand how the double-negative `[^\S\r\n]` works.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/go9IbZ/2)