# How to remove all extra spaces while keeping the lines

Tags: javascript, html

I need to remove white-spaces while keeping the lines

Before:

```
I brought           a            Banana
I sold                a Banana
I           brought a Apple
```

After: NO WHITE SPACES or big space at the begining of the line

```
I brought a Banana
I sold a Banana
I brought a Apple
```

All of the tutorials removes the white space but it didn't keep me the lines so it became all the words in one line:

I need to do this because after I use the .replace method in JavaScript, I get a bunch of white spaces but need to keep the lines so I can reorder the words.

Comment: str.replace(/[ \t]{2,}/g, ' ')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to replace multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match whitespace but not newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469080/match-whitespace-but-not-newlines)

Comment: you probably want `str.replace(/[^\S\r\n]+/g,' ');`

Comment: None of this code works for my situation, I don't know how to explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string with `\n` to map them:

```js
var str = `I brought    a            Banana
I                   sold a Apple
I       sold a             Banana`;
str = str.split('\n').map(l => l.replace(/\s+/g,' ')).join('\n');
console.log(str);
```

OR: Simply `str.replace(/[ \t]{1,}/g, ' ')`

Where

`\t` matches a tab character (ASCII 9)

`{1,}` Quantifier — Matches between 1 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

```js
var str = `I    brought    a            Banana
I                   sold a Apple
I       sold a             Banana`;
str = str.replace(/[ \t]{1,}/g, ' ');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply split the data by the space, filter them out and then add a single space.

```
var str = `I brought    a            Banana
I                   sold a Apple
I       sold a             Banana`;

str.split(' ').filter(String).join(' ');
```

Comment: str.split(' ').filter(String) 

Then look at the array and only save the elements you need

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way

```js
console.log(`I brought    a            Banana
I                   sold a Apple
I       sold a             Banana`.replace(/ +/g," "))
```