# Split string with regex by new lines, symbols and withspaces in python

Tags: python, regex, whitespace, symbols, tokenize

I'm new to regex library, and I'm trying to make from a text like this

```
"""constructor SquareGame new(){
let square=square;
}"""
```

This outputs a list:

```
['constructor', 'SquareGame', 'new', '(', ')', '{', '\n', 'let', 'square', '=',  'square', ';', '}']
```

I need to create a list of tokens separated by white spaces, new lines and this symbols `{}()[].;,+-*/&|<>=~`.

I used `re.findall('[,;.()={}]+|\S+|\n', text)` but seems to separate tokens by withe spaces and new lines only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will only match based on the characters that you indicated and I think this is a safer method.

```
>>> re.findall(r"\w+|[{}()\[\].;,+\-*/&|<>=~\n]", text)
['constructor', 'SquareGame', 'new', '(', ')', '{', '\n', 'let', 'square', '=', 'square', ';', '\n', '}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'\w+|[^\w \t]', text)
```

To avoid matching *any* Unicode horizontal whitespace use

```
re.findall(r'\w+|[^\w \t\u00A0\u1680\u2000-\u200A\u202F\u205F\u3000]', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ra0AWi/1). **Details**:

- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `|` - or
- `[^\w \t]` - a single non-word char that is not a space and a tab char (so, all vertical whitespace is matched).

You may add more horizontal whitespace chars to exclude into the `[^\w \t]` character class, see their list at [Match whitespace but not newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469080). The regex will look like `\w+|[^\w \t\u00A0\u1680\u2000-\u200A\u202F\u205F\u3000]`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CK1QD4):

```
import re
pattern = r"\w+|[^\w \t]"
text = "constructor SquareGame new(){\nlet square=square;\n}"
print ( re.findall(pattern, text) )
# => ['constructor', 'SquareGame', 'new', '(', ')', '{', '\n', 'let', 'square', '=', 'square', ';', '\n', '}']
```

Comment: Thanks this works, even if i ddon't understand your code so much