# In Python, how to use re.sub() to replace all literal Unicode spaces?

Tags: python, unicode

In Python, when I use readlines() to read from a text file, something that was originally a space will become a literal Unicode character, as shown follows. Where \u2009 is a space in the original text file.

So, I'm using re.sub() to replace these Unicode literal spaces with a normal space.

My code is as follows:

```
x = "Significant increases in all the lipoprotein fractions were observed in infected untreated mice compared with normal control mice. Treatment with 100 and 250\u2009mg/kg G. lucidum extract produced significant reduction in serum total cholesterol (TC) and low-density cholesterol (LDL-C) contents compared with 500\u2009mg/kg G. lucidum and CQ."

x = re.sub(r'[\x0b\x0c\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x85\xa0\u1680\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000]', " ", x)
```

I don't know if I'm right?

Although the program looks normal, I'm not sure because I don't understand regular expressions well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub("[^\S \t\n\r\f\v]",' ',x)`

should do the trick (based on *docs.python.org*: [`re` — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/re.html)):

You know that `[]` is used to indicate a set of characters, and characters that are not within a range can be matched by *complementing the set*. If the first character of the set is `'^'`, all the characters that are not in the set will be matched.

The regex pattern `[^\S \t\n\r\f\v]` reads as

- `^` (U+005E,  *Circumflex Accent*) **Not**   **（**
- `\S` (*not a whitespace*) **or**
- (*Space*)  **or**
- `\t` (*Character Tabulation*)  **or**
- `\n` (*Line Feed (LF)*) **or**
- `\r` (*Carriage Return (CR)*) **or**
- `\f` (*Form Feed (FF)*) **or**
- `\v` (*Line Tabulation*)

  **）**

Distributing the outer not (i.e., the complementing `^` in the character class) with [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), this is equivalent to “whitespace **except** any of `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`.”

Including both `\r` and `\n` in the pattern correctly handles all of Unix (LF), classic Mac OS (CR), and Windows-ish (CR+LF) [newline conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation).
Included a space itself (we do not need translate a space to space)…

`\s`
For Unicode (`str`) patterns:
Matches Unicode whitespace characters (which includes `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`, and also many other characters, for example the non-breaking spaces mandated by typography rules in many languages)…

Partially applied the following answer: [Regex – Match whitespace but not newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25956935/)

Answer (score 0):

quick solution:

```py
x = " ".join(x.split())
```